# Missing array data after for-loop in JS

Tags: javascript

The question was - How the array data disappeared after a for-loop.

Explanation - Initially the variable "bra_data" receives a string such as "6 !" or any "x !" or any math operator in "x operator y" form. Then it is split into an array.

```
var bra_data = bra_data.split(" "); //bra data array
```

Then using index of, i is set to the array item containing the math operator.

```
if(bra_data.indexOf("!")!=-1) {
i = bra_data.indexOf("!");
}
```

Then using the array index, the answer is processed.

```
var x = (bra_data[i - 1] * 1);
var i, x_fact;
x_fact = 1;
alert(bra_data[i - 1]); //A
alert(bra_data[i]); //B
for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
  x_fact = x_fact * i;
}
alert(bra_data[i - 1]); //C
```

After processing at //C, it alerts the array item as "undefined", why?

Comment: Surely the first line should result in an error. Unless you have set `i` but not included it in your code. If you set `i` before, it gets reset in your for loop.

Comment: look at your variable `i`

Comment: 1) You aren't giving `i` a value before using it. 2) `x` seems to be assigned to some magic number. 3) You haven't told us what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: what's the length of `bra_data` and what's the value of `i` at the last statement?

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It was all because I used variable 'i' in the array and the same variable on the for loop. But check my answer below, another code where I did the same, yet "bra_data[i - 1]" comes clear in the last line. I'm still puzzled though.

Comment: Because if `x` is 6, and there are only two items in the array ... well you work it out.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answers. Using a different variable 'l' on for-loop helped it.

```
var x = (bra_data[i - 1] * 1);
var l, x_fact;
x_fact = 1;
alert(bra_data[i - 1]); //A
alert(bra_data[i]); //B
for (l = 1; l <= x; l++) {
x_fact = x_fact * i;
}
alert(bra_data[i - 1]); //C
```

It is a silly mistake but the following code worked well. Hence the variable never crossed my mind.

```
var i, x_fact, x_minus_y, x_minus_y_fact;
x_fact=1;
var x = (bra_data[i-1]*1);
var y = (bra_data[i+1]*1);
for(i=1; i<=x; i++)  {
x_fact= x_fact*i;
} 
x_minus_y = (x*1)-(y*1);
x_minus_y_fact=1;
for(i=1; i<=x_minus_y; i++)  {
x_minus_y_fact= x_minus_y_fact*i;
}
var answer = (x_fact*1)/(x_minus_y_fact*1);
alert(bra_data[i-1]);
```

Thank you so much for your quick comments. You saved my night.

Comment: Your "fixed" code doesn't look much like your original code and still contains errors in it. If you want to add detail to your original question, please edit it instead of creating an answer.

Comment: @MikeC Corrected the answer as well as added background to the question. Thank you.